# Is there a way to browse questions freezing them at the time you clicked "Questions"?

Tags: discussion, questions

When I click questions, now and then during the day, I try to browse them and answer what I can (or what it takes less time during working hours), but if I distract for a second or happen to click "Questions" during rush hours, when I click on the next page, they "follow" me.
The last questions will be the top ones in the next page, sometimes there will be just 3 or 4 new, which is understandable, as the traffic to this website is quite high.
Although, is it possible to "freeze" the questions at the moment you decided to browse them?

Comment: You should probably use a tag filtered page. There are too many questions coming in too quickly.

Comment: or you can be gimmicky =/... you can open Questions page in a separate tab, along with a few of the following pages in separate tabs. Then when you browse questions, open those in a a separate tab. That way you can just close the question tab and then return to the exact same question pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although, is it possible to "freeze" the questions at the moment you decided to browse them?

No, it isn't possible.

However, there's some things you *can* do:

- Filter by tag, so you see only questions that are interesting to you. Stack Overflow gets over 13,000 questions *per day*, so, if you filter them by tags you're interested in, you'll have a much higher chance of finding something interesting.
- Use the Stack Exchange iOS / Android app, which has infinite scrolling, so you can keep scrolling down the same list of questions forever.
- Set the page size to the maximum of 50 questions per page:

  [image]

  This way, you can stay on one page for longer, and you won't have to paginate as much.